# Any application to render what key I am pressing on screen in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, display, osx-leopard

I am an IT instructor who is using MacBook Pro. I have saw a screen cast which they were using MacBook too. It's interesting that while they were demonstrating how to use an application the key they hit also show on their desktop, for example: "fn + F9".

So I have googling around for this application. I think you may know this application, or suggest me to something similar. :)

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/407334/how-can-i-see-a-visual-overlay-of-shortcut-keys-ive-pressed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout [Mouseposé](http://www.boinx.com/mousepose/overview/). It appears to have exactly what you are after:

> ### Clearly Show What You Type
>
> With keystroke visualisation, your audience sees the keys you press. This way they will understand your demonstration much better. Useful for product demos and trainings.
>
> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, joshhunt! This is what I am looking for my work.

Answer (score 1):

Some screencast programs allow you to show the key presses (strokes) used right within the video they create itself.

An example is [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm) or [iShowU](http://shinywhitebox.com/home/home.html). They both have the ability to show key presses inside the movies they create.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the application Keyboard from an old version of OSX. Think it was ditched in OSX 10.3