# Mac software that displays pressed keys onscreen

Tags: keyboard, osx-mountain-lion, screen-capture, screencasts, on-screen-keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I see a visual overlay of shortcut keys I’ve pressed?](https://superuser.com/questions/407334/how-can-i-see-a-visual-overlay-of-shortcut-keys-ive-pressed)

I'm planning to start a coding side-project in mid-November, and I would like to record some of my work on it as a screencast.  I'll be doing this on a Mac running Mountain Lion.

I'd like to do one special thing, though: I'd like to be able to include a small display in one corner of my screen that pops up whenever I press a key combination including a meta-key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, for instance, or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).  To me, this makes it much easier to follow.

So I'm looking for **either** screen-recording software which provides that functionality as a plug-in **or** a stand-alone program that will display key combinations onscreen.  It should be able to float in the foreground over whatever I'm doing, but remain invisible (or very subtle) unless I'm holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>or<kbd>Fn</kbd>.  It should also work without my intervention (i.e., I shouldn't have to manually do something extra every time I'm pressing some keys I want it to display).  Does anyone know of a program or combination of programs that will do this (paid is fine)?

Edit: in earlier versions of Mac OS X, there was an option under Sticky Keys to turn on this functionality.  But I *hate* Sticky Keys, so I'm trying to avoid it unless I absolutely need it for this.

Comment: I've not heard of anything like it.  Maybe this should be your first coding project?

Comment: Very meta, but I'm allowing someone else to pick the project I do (long story), so I don't think it will work out for this one.  I suppose I can write something prior to starting the screencast series if I really must, but I'm still hopeful there's *something* out there which can be bent to this purpose...

Comment: I have version 2 of this software (and am upgrading next month).  They may have what you are after.  http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/partners.htm#leapingbrain

Comment: Another related question at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52618/how-can-i-show-typing-keyboard-in-record-screen/52636#52636).

Comment: Ahh!  Thank you for the link, Lauri.  My search-fu failed me on this one.  Mouseposé looks like exactly what I was looking for.  Embarrassingly, I can't summarily close my own question, only vote to close it, but the linked question is equivalent.